# Google analytics numbers in graph do not match numbers in table for a single day

Tags: google-analytics

Google analytics is not displaying same numbers in the grid and in the graph with a custom dimension included.
This is Behavior -> site content -> all pages report.

Is this a bug, or I am doing something wrong?
[image]

Comment: What color is the badge next to the report title - green or yellow? If it's yellow, what is the message you get when you hover over it?

Comment: @Reve it was yellow, and it said This report is based on 31.02% of sessions. Learn more
The table rows have been filtered to include only data for "Category". The graph and table headers include totals for all data.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple “truths” you must consider:

- You are looking at sampled data. The % mentioned is about the sessions. Not the metric you currently look at. So, the sessions of your sample size did create 755.505 pageviews on 01/11/2018. That is the dot.
- You added a secondary dimension “Category”. Thus, the table returns the table rows containing a category in your sample. That is 743.300 results.
- And then we have the number of the actual size of pageviews. 4.671.237

To verify you can remove the secondary dimension and still see 755.505 pageview on the dot (you sample). Then the table total should be 755.505 too.

Comment: Nice listing! I would just highlight that the difference between the graph/dot and the table is all in your second point: a pageview hit that does not have a Category will disappear from the table when Category is added as a secondary dimension. There's no "(not set)" for custom dimensions. Sampling should be affecting the total number of pageviews in the graph and table equally.